# Clojure2d: drawing on the canvas silently fails if it has been resized

Tags: clojure, java-2d, clojure-2d

The following code successfully displays a blank canvas with a small red square:

```
(ns test-rect
  (:require [clojure2d.core :as c2d])
  (:require '[clojure2d.extra.utils :refer [show-image]]))

(c2d/with-canvas->
  (c2d/canvas 100 100)
;  (c2d/resize 100 100)
  (c2d/set-color :red)
  (c2d/rect 50 50 10 10)
  show-image)
```

However if I uncomment the call to *resize*, the red square is not drawn any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resize` creates a new canvas that has to be passed into its own `with-canvas`.

For example:

```clj
(let [canvas (c2d/canvas 100 100)]
  (c2d/with-canvas-> (c2d/resize canvas 100 100)
    (c2d/set-color :red)
    (c2d/rect 50 50 10 10)
    show-image))
```